# How to remove the h2 div with specific text

Tags: jquery, html

Here is the structure of html

```
<ul id="products" class="subcategory-products products">
<h1 class="page-title">Beers</h1>
<h2><a href="http://localhost:8888/brb.local/product-category/core-range">Core Range</a></h2>
```

How should I remove the h2 div with Core Range text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

The `:contains` selector will check for "`Core Range`" at any poistion e.g. "`Test Core Range 1`", "`Core Range 123`" will always be true for contains.

Use filter to filter out your matched text.

```
var $h2 = $('h2').filter(function() {
    return $(this).text() === "Core Range";    
});

$h2.remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
$('a:contains("Core Range")').closest('h2').remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**:contains**](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) selector:

```
$('h2 a:contains("Core Range")').parent().remove();
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LRK3b/)**

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
$('h2').remove();
```

Comment: This would remove more `<h2>` tags than the ones that were specified.